# Android simulate button press

Tags: android, mouseevent

I am trying to execute an event mouse press within my android application.  When the user enters a CARRIAGE RETURN when entering text into a text field.  I would like to execute a mouse button press on an ADD button when that character is detected in my OnClickListener for that EditText ui.

Answer (score 0):

Peter -

It sounds like what you want to do is override the EditorAction for the given EditText, and then programmatically perform the same action as the OnClickListener.  For example:

```
EditText inputText; //This is either created in code or inflated via XML
Button addButton;   //This is either created in code or inflated via XML

inputText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        addButton.performClick();
        //Tell the system you consumed the action event
        return true;
    }
});
```

The actionId can be a useful property too, as it reports the specific action (DONE, NEXT, etc.) based on the soft keyboard method shown...but keep in mind that if the user presses enter from a hardware keyboard the action will ALWAYS be `EditorInfo.IME_NULL`, so it may not serve your purpose to monitor this value.

This is a safer method than overriding KeyEvent listeners, as you run less risk of consuming events you don't want and didn't know you stole.

Hope that helps!